# Gradle task run finished with non-zero exit value 100 when running java

Tags: java, linux, gradle

```
 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'home/comp/Downloads/jdk-13.0.2+8/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 100
```

This has happened before and I tried updating Gradle and reinstalled java  using a different method. Now the problem has come back. Any help appreciated.

Full build scan can be seen here:
https://scans.gradle.com/s/flb2fv7dwffnq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encountered the same issue today with the same error message and code. In my case I had a shadowprocess running that occupied the port. Once I manage to shut that down I could run the process normally with no problems.

This error seam to indicate that the port is already in use and therefore you can't connect to the port.
Try checking if you have another program or process already occupying the port you wish to use. Also check that your build isn't already up and running cause having a second of the same build running will be blocked by the first as it was in my case with my shadow process.

Hope this help :)